# copy value by using v lookup and LEN

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, sheet 1 contain the data, sheet 2 will return the value from sheet 1.

sheet 1

```
   A         B
A40C7A4 BN01:Fruits for Aug-Banana
DB76FE1 BN01:Fruits for Aug-Lemon
9CCA14D BN01:Fruits for Aug-Kiwi
0274DFE BN01:Fruits for Aug-Apple
```

sheet 2

```
   A        B
Banana  sheet1,column A value here
Lemon   
Kiwi    
Apple
```

I've tried using vlookup wildcard, but there is no value copied. Can someone please guide me on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason which prohibits you from spliting text in Column B and then using  a combination of Index & Match function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use VLOOKUP to find something in a column to the right then return an associated value from a column to the left.

Try,

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH("*"&A2, Sheet1!B:B, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: I'd leave it for future viewers of this post who require something more complex.